# How is possible to use React Hook that way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I recently see this code from someone:

```js
const FindLangKey = (key, observer = "") => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const languageArray = useContext(GlobalContext)?.LanguageArray;

  useMemo(
    () => {
      if (languageArray?.length > 0) {
        const ObjIndex = languageArray?.findIndex((obj) => obj.FormKey === key);
        setText(
          languageArray[ObjIndex]?.Value?.length > 0
            ? ArabicToPersian(languageArray[ObjIndex]?.Value)
            : ArabicToPersian(languageArray[ObjIndex]?.Key)
        );
      }
    },
    [JSON.stringify(languageArray), observer],
    observer
  );

  return text;
};

export default FindLangKey;
```

it is a function but as you can see you can call react hooks inside of it.

which is bizarre because React wouldn't allow to call hooks inside of regular functions. also, there's another thing I wondered. that, if I call this function inside of another regular function.

it will say that's not possible to use hooks inside of it, until I return something. it seems you can call hooks inside of regular functions if they have return value.

for example, this will not work:

```js
export const words = [ { langId:1, word: FindLangKey('something') } ]
```

but this will make it work :

```js
export const words = ()=>{
const word = FindLangKey('something');
const data = [
langId:1,
word:word,
]
return word;
}
```

I'm really reallly confused about what is going on. please consider help me understand why such code works. I think I might forgot something about how React works.

Comment: `FindLangKey` is assumed to be a component by the linter, because it starts with a capital letter. But it can't be called properly with `<FindLangKey />` because it doesn't take a `props` object. It looks like the person who wrote this code isn't great at React, and the function should instead be called `useFindLangKey`, so the linter recognizes it as a hook, and it should called as a hook in any other component.

Comment: @AndyRay the thing I wonder is how it is possible to call it inside of regular function? everything starts with `use` can be called only inside of function components or another custom hook. 
but it is usable even inside of regular functions. 
how?!

Comment: React doesn't exacty "prevent" you from calling hooks in vanilla functions. You can call `useState()` anywhere, but if it's not in a component or hook, it generates the console warning "Warning: Invalid hook call.". The ESLint React plugin also warns you about using hooks in the wrong place. `useState` is just a function, and you can call functions anywhere in Javascript. The console and ESLint warnings lets you know that the hook won't do what you expect by calling it outside a hook/component.

Comment: @AndyRay I used CRA for development. and actually it wasn't ESLint warning. it broke the app all together. 
but this function just works like nothing special is happening. 

I tried to call built-in hooks inside of vanilla functions and it didn't work. until I returned something from that function. I don't really know what is going on

Comment: CRA comes with ESLint, but you should read console errors and warnings to understand what's going on. Also, your `const words = () => ...` doesn't do anything, it just declares a function. The body doesn't get executed until you call `words()`, so `FindLangKey` never gets called either. `const words = [` calls `FindLagKey` in place. So you might just be overlooking when functions get called vs when they don't.

Comment: @AndyRay I called it and it worked. but for some reason if your vanilla function don't return anything. it will say "invalid hook call" and it breaks the app. it is an error not warning. 
this `FindLangKey` function doesn't follow the rules I guess. I doesn't have such problems

Comment: That may mean you're calling `words()` inside a React component, which makes the hooks valid, which is code you don't show us. This question now has too many comments. If you can edit this with a live reproducible example of what you're talking about, that might help clarify what you're trying to understand specifically.

Comment: @AndyRay the `but this will make it work :` part was the example. I used it inside of regular function and it worked.

Comment: Again, you do not show us how `words` is used. If that’s the code you’re asking about, you should include it in the question. Your words function also does not contain valid JavaScript.

Comment: @AndyRay sorry comments are getting too long. `FindLangKey` just returns string. it looks for matching language key inside of large array and returns a string. that's it. 

and `words` as you can see is an object with Id and returned string from `FindLangKey`

Comment: Again, you do not show us how `words` is used.

Answer (score 2):

There are rules in programming. There are also rules in React. If you won't follow all of them, it doesn't mean that your code will fail or your application will crash. Some of them are just necessary to keep your code clean and make it understandable for other developers.

Same with React Hooks. Calling a hook outside *React component* will crash your app. But not using the proper naming convention, which is starting the name of the function with `use...` keyword, won't crash your app. It's just a naming convention, a hint for other developers that this is a *custom hook*.

> which is bizarre because React wouldn't allow to call hooks inside of regular functions

*Custom hook* is **a regular** function. The main difference between a *regular function* and a *custom hook* is fact, that *custom hooks* can be called **only** within React context (inside *React components*).

> for example, this will not work:
>
> `export const words = [ { langId:1, word: FindLangKey('something') } ]`

Of course it will work, but **only within** React context (inside *React components*).

Summarizing - following the React Hooks rules is not always obligatory and missing some of them will not crash your code, but will for sure help you to keep your code clean and avoid unexpected behavior of your application.